# How to Connect Excel to ONLINE Mysql Database in my Domain using ODBC?

Tags: mysql, database, excel, odbc

I've been trying to connect Excel to online mysql database.

Im using 5.1 DSN ODBC, gone through the process but when im establishing the connection of mysql and excel an error occured.

`Connection Failed: [HY000] [MYSQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access denied for user 'icafeown'@'118.252.49.9'(userpassword: YES)`

I've been in the same questions like this but i cant establish the correct connection.
im using Cpanel for the domain and i already used `Remote MySQL`.

and the Database: Dropdown are empty. [image: ODBC]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access denied means that you've successfully established a TCP connection to the MySQL server, but don't have appropriate permissions within MySQL to actually "log in" to the server.

Usually this is because of a mis-match on the 'host' portion of the MySQL user account. e.g. You may have created a `someone@example.com` account in MySQL, but your client's IP address cannot be reverse-lookuped to confirm that it is "example.com". MySQL only sees the IP you connect from, not the hostname. If your 118.252.49.9 can't be resolved to be 'example.com', you won't get it.

Same goes for connections on the same machine. You may have your someone@example.com MySQL account, but MySQL will see a connection come in from 127.0.0.1/localhost, which is NOT "example.com".

Comment: so you're saying that I need my IP '118.252.49.9' to be 'example.com'?  or something else?

Comment: No, just that the username=icafown, host=118.252.49.9 is not a known account in MySQL. How MySQL sees you connecting must match what you're connecting as.